# Unable to use latest version of jsPDF, gives error

Tags: jspdf

I am trying to use jsPDF, but when I use the CDN URL given below,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.2.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
```

We get the following error,

```
Summary:4644 Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
```

But when I use the one below which is the older version it works,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

Is the new version only for node?

Answer (score 2):

You should use const doc = new window.jspdf.jsPDF(); in the newer verions.
Instead of const doc = new jsPDF();.

Here is where I found it:
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2972